# JQTouch Windows Phone 7

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, jqtouch

Is there a hack for using the JQtouch library on windows 7 phones? Or is there a good alternative for that?

Thanx
Stefan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Tom Squires said, jQTouch only supports WebKit. In fact, it pretty much targets at iOS Safari. I have been developing with [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/). Even though it's still at alpha, IMHO, it offers more than most of the frameworks out there. It seems to have good support for WM7.0 as well: take a look at [their browser support matrix](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer no. JQtouch is based on webkit, the version of IE on WP7 isnt.

I would recomend testing the Jquery library. The browser on wp7 is supposed to be similar to the desktop version so you may have some luck.